# Postresql not connecting to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, node-modules, heroku-postgres

im using heroku to host my site however it keeps spitting out the same error which is

> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212104+00:00 app[web.1]:AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212106+00:00 app[web.1]:at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1036:3)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212107+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket. (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:94:23)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212109+00:00 app[web.1]:at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212110+00:00 app[web.1]:at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212112+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212113+00:00 app[web.1]:at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212115+00:00 app[web.1]:at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212116+00:00 app[web.1]:at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
>
> 2018-05-06T19:28:52.212118+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onread >>(net.js:607:20)

this is how im connecting (taken straight off of herokus website)

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const router = express.Router();

const pool = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});

pool.connect();
```

I found out what the error was:

the error was that i did not have a db create. i decided to use elephantSQL and from their i connected to elephantSQL with pgadmin and recreated my database. it works perfect now

to see how this works see : https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/pgadmin.html

im more than happy to answer some questions

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't really a solution but it might help you out. This happens to me on node 8 (and 10) but when I downgraded to node 7 it seems to work fine. I'll be watching this post to see if someone comes up with a better fix.

Comment: thank i solved the problem yesterday but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Care to share what your solution was?

I've also found that installing the npm modules from node 7 but running with node 8 works fine. Must be some npm module, but I haven't been able to dig up which one yet.

Comment: ye ofcourse ill update my answer to the correct code i just had to host my database with elephantSQL and pgadmin then it would work